# Do the notations in these diagrams mean some kind of compositions?

Tags: category-theory

In Categories for the Working Mathematician, the definiton of a monoidal category has some diagrams, wherein I am not sure about the meanings of some notations. (I have some intuition that the diagrams used in categories are about    commutativity. )

For example, in (5), what do $1 \square \alpha$ and $\alpha \square 1$ mean in (5)? Do they mean some "compositions" of $1$ (the identity functor on $B$),  bifunctor $\square$, and $\alpha_{a,b,c}$?

Similarly, in (7), what do $1 \square \lambda$ and $\rho \square 1$ mean?

Thanks.

(Sorry for using the screenshots, because I can't reproduce the diagrams here.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's the application of the functor to the morphism $(\alpha, 1)$.

Comment: It’s defined in the book

Comment: Just a remark off topic that might interest you: demand $(8)$ has been shown to be redundant by - if I am not mistaking - Kelly. It can be shown to be a consequence of $(5)$, $(6)$ and $(7)$.

Comment: @Randall Thanks. Where is it?

Comment: I don’t have it in front of me, but I think where he first defines monoidal categories.

Comment: Oh, it's actually defined in your screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context $\alpha\square1$ denotes the arrow $\alpha_{a,b,c}\square1_d$.

Further $1\square\lambda$ is used as a notation for arrow $1_a\square\lambda_c$ and $\rho\square1$ as a notation for $\rho_a\square1_c$.

It is just a matter of avoiding subscripts that speak for themselves.

Comment: Thanks. is $1$ a functor from $B$ to $B$? According to your reply, it seems to be a natural transformation from what functor to what functor?

Comment: Furthermore, what does $α_{a,b,c}□1_c.$ mean? Some kind of composition? I look at the objects before and after the arrow in the diagram, but am uncertain.

Comment: There was a typo in my answer (repaired now) and it must be $\alpha_{a,b,c}\square1_d$ (not $1_c$). Further $\square:B\times B\to B$ is a (bi)functor. For objects $a,b$ we write $a\square b$ for $\square(a,b)$. Same for arrows: $f\square g$ instead of $\square(f,g)$ and we can take $f=\alpha_{a,b,c}$ and $g=1_d$. The arrows $\alpha_{a,b,c}\square1_d$ are the components again of a natural isomorphism.

Comment: We have identity functor $\mathsf{id}_B$ together with a natural isomorphism $\mathsf{id}_B\to\mathsf{id}_B$ having all identities as components.